# Does anyone have a diagram of the HC-130J wing dimensions and fuel tank locations?

Tags: c-130

Looking for a drawing of the HC-130J that includes fuel tank locations and wing dimension (more than just wingspan)

Comment: You are looking for something [like this](http://aviadejavu.ru/Images6/AN/AN83-2/13-1.jpg) except with dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the technical data, i recommend you the "service news" material, that can be checked out here: https://www.lockheedmartin.com/content/dam/lockheed-martin/aero/documents/sustainment/csc/service-news/sn-mag-v1-v10/V6N4.pdf.

For an overview, there's a diagram:
[image: Lockheed C-130 Hercules]

(diagram link: https://airwingmedia.com/downloads/lockheed-c130-hercules/).

Comment: Thanks, great resources.